# Angular 7: Jquery and Bootstrap not working

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

After installing Bootstrap and Jquery using this command npm install bootstrap --save still not able to get if bootstrap is installed in angular or not

[image]

Output:
[image]

HTML Template:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" routerLink="/page1">Page 1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <button type="btn btn-primary">Hello</button>
 </div> 

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Index.html: [Only if i am adding jquery & Bootstrap cdn in index.html then its working but i guess this is not a right solution right ?]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularAssignment</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


</head>
<body class="hello">
  <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Dániel Barta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2302473/d%C3%A1niel-barta) suggested, doing `npm install` **isn't** enough. Now you have to import your installed package to your application.

On the root level of your application find the file called **angular.json**.

**Bootstrap**:

1. In that json file, search for `"styles"` property which is representing an array of paths
2. Add `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` to the end of that array

**JQuery**

1. In that json file, search for `"scripts"` property which is representing an array of, again paths, but this time, js files.
2. Add `"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"` to the end of that array

If you want to use bootstrap.js, add the its path bellow jquery import:

**JQuery + bootstrap.js**:

"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",

"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"

So, **Bootstrap css + jquery + bootstrap.js** imports should look like this:

```
 "styles": [
     "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  ],
  "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
  ],
```

If you already have your own paths in styles or scripts arrays, leave them, and add these paths to the bottom of the arrays.

Best advice I can give you is to go through Angular documentation, research a bit about installing packages and how it all works.

Comment: I f you can see the conversation btw @Dániel Barta  wherever you are suggesting that only i did. and the import also is looks similar.

Comment: try adding ./ instead of ../ before node_modules

Answer (score 0):

If you can see them in the node_module folder. It's installed. But you also have to import the module and the CSS file in the Angular application. You can find a good material for Bootstrap [here](https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/), and for the jQuery, you have to go to the *.angular-cli.json* file and it it to the `scripts` property:
`"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]`

Comment: I used this below approch see
 "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            ],

Comment: If i give ../ before node_modules then also same result is coming

Comment: See Question i had added HTML Template also

Comment: Have you rerun `ng serve` since you modified _.angular-cli.json_?

Comment: You mixed things up a little. For example, your last button should be ```<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Hello</button>```

Comment: Yea @daniel that was a mistake but after correcting also same result is coming , run "ng serve "again, In this case at least navigation should come if button is not defined corretly